# How do you wget a page protected with shibboleth authentication?

Tags: ssl, wget, certificate, shibboleth

I am attempting to scrape data off of pages protected by shibboleth authentication.  I was having trouble getting cURL and webisoget to work correctly.  So, I am trying wget, because I was thinking I could pass my certificate and grab the pages I wanted.  However, I am also having trouble with this and I have had difficulty finding documentation concerning my problem.

Here is the wget command I am attempting to execute:

```
>wget --no-check-certificate --certificate=www.washington.edu.crt https://www.washington.edu/cec/i/INFO200A2821.html
```

This is what that command returns:

```
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
--2011-05-28 00:32:37--  https://www.washington.edu/cec/i/INFO200A2821.html
Resolving www.washington.edu... 140.142.16.69, 140.142.11.167, 140.142.15.8
Connecting to www.washington.edu|140.142.16.69|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify www.washington.edu's certificate, issued by `/C=ZA/ST=Wes
tern Cape/L=Cape Town/O=Thawte Consulting cc/OU=Certification Services Division/
CN=Thawte Premium Server CA/emailAddress=premium-server@thawte.com':
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 807 [text/html]
Saving to: `INFO200A2821.html.2'

100%[=====================================> ] 807         --.-K/s   in 0s

2011-05-28 00:32:38 (6.78 MB/s) - `INFO200A2821.html.2' saved [807/807]
```

However, even though I receive a page, it does not contain the information I hope to scrape.  The page that returns is one that contains a form that auto-submits a form upon loading.  The form contains hidden input fields for the pubcookie and the relay_url.

I am able to access the page when logging in with my credentials.  However, I am struggling on automating this and grabbing the information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do that with wget. Shibboleth is an implementation of the SAML web SSO profile, and it expects you to have a valid session to access the protected resource. Without a valid session it will redirect your to the WAIF page, for you to select the appropriate identity provider. There are a series steps that must be performed before you can access the resource.

You could try to use something like [Mechanize.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.68/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) for Perl to automate the authentication procedure and then retrieve the protected resource.